# How to get user pointed GPS coordinates?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

So I want a user to connect to Google maps and point to some location. Now I want to receive those GPS coordinates from where the user pointed in Google maps into my app. How do I go about doing that, and is there example code?  I have the basic code down here. Also, if the user enters, Chipotle in San Francisco, how would I be able to grab those coordinates and use them in my app?

```
public class UserMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private double user_latitude = Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().getUserLatitude;
    private double user_longitude = Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().getUserLongitude;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        //Add a market in syndey Australia
        LatLng syndey = new LatLng(user_latitude,user_longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(syndey).title("Market in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(syndey));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10),2000,null);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a marker by calling `googleMap.addMarker()` like you did in your example depending where the user clicks on the map with [OnMapClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener)

Then you can get the current position of a marker by calling `mMarker.getPosition()`. You can also add a drag listener to your marks so you can update your position after every drag.

From the API: [Marker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker)

If you also want to get coordinates just by a name, then you need for example to do a call to the google API and get the lat/long from their API.

EDIT: If you do not want to place a Marker, you can just use the [CameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition) and get the lat/long from that object.

Cheers

Comment: do you have a link where I can learn how to call the google api?

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro
Unfortunately I do not have a code example atm. But you should find a lot of stuff here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm currently doing the same thing, so once I've got the code I can share.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/

google has different api's but they are all pretty easy and all very straight forward if you follow the guidlines